# Unable to use jQuery in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to figure out why I am not able to use jQuery in my extension, I am an absolute beginner, but in theory this should do the job:

**manifest**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "iD",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "description" : "iD",
    "browser_action" : {
        // "default_icon" : "icon.png",
        "default_popup" : "popup.html",
        "default_title" : "iD"
    },
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "app.js" ],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$("body").append("Hello World");
```

Yet all I see is an empty popup instead of "Hello World"

Comment: Are you sure your app.js runs AFTER the HTML finished loading? Try window.onload or a setTimeout to check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inject [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) into extension pages (popup included).

You need to:

1. Read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).
2. Add the scripts directly to your popup:

   ```
   <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   ```
3. *(the comment raises a valid point)* For all DOM manipulation, wrap your code in [the `ready()` event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     /* Manipulate DOM here */
   });
   ```