# Use Polymer elements in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, polymer

At the moment I'm writing a Chrome extension and in the `popup.html` I want to use some Polymer elements, but my problem is that none of them are rendered in the popup. My `popup.html` looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
        <script src="js/popup.js"></script>             
    </head>

    <body>
        <paper-tabs id="tabBar" class="bottom fit" selected="{{selected}}">
            <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my `popup.js`

```
window.onload = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
}
```

And here is my content script:

```
function loadRes(res) {
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');

        link.setAttribute('rel', 'import');
        link.setAttribute('href', res);

        link.onload = function() {
            resolve(res);
        };

        document.head.appendChild(link);
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    loadRes(chrome.extension.getURL("polymer/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"))
    .then(loadRes(chrome.extension.getURL("polymer/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html")))

});
```

This code comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30034988/2047987) and it should work, so do you have any ideas what is wrong with my code or have I misunderstood something? I thought that the code from `popup.js` is executed when the popup is loading and and referenced polymer files are injected into the `popup.html` file. Isn't that right? I also added all polymer files to `web_accessible_resources` and my `content_scripts` runs at `document_start`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply a solution that injects Polymer into a regular webpage (through content scripts) to your own UI page.

Extensions' own pages [never run any content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31590214/934239), and you don't need any complicated steps to include Polymer. You can just <del>do it the regular way</del> - you can add `<link>` elements to your markup and there is no need to call `getURL`.

**Update:** due to [Chrome Extensions' CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), an [additional step](http://shortpgh.com/2014/10/22/how-to-use-polymer-in-a-chrome-app/) is needed (`vulcanize` or [`polybuild`](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polybuild)) to get rid of inline code.

All the complication happens when you're trying to do that to a third-party page you have no direct control over. This is not the case with extension's own pages.

---

For the record, you're most certainly misusing `tabs.query` - it does not send any messages in any case, it gives you information about open tabs in a callback (that you don't have).

Comment: Okay thank you for this. But if I create a normal Webpage with Polymer elements which runs great on my webserver and I load this page as popup.html in my extension nothing is rendered in the popup. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Learning to [debug the popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) would be a good idea. It's probably a CSP violation - and there are mentions on the web how to solve it. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! With [`vulcanize`](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) I have solved the problem. Small thing to point out from the link: `--csp` is removed from `vulcanize` and you have to use [`crisper`](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper) instead. An example how to use them together is written on the crisper GitHub page

Comment: Note: `polybuild` is an all-in-one tool that includes `vulcanize` and `crisper` - and is the [recommended solution by Polymer devs](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/762#issuecomment-175838923).